# Use of unassigned out parameter 'q'

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

Getting error use of unassigned out parameter 'q' and 'g', please correct where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;   

class Program  
{  
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        int p = 23;  
        int f = 24;  
        Fun(out p, out f);  
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p, f);  

    }  
    static void Fun(out int q, out int g)  
    {  
        q = q+1;  
        g = g+1;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to go read the documentation for `out`.  You don't seem to understand what it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is exactly what the compiler *says* you're doing wrong - you're trying to *read* from an `out` parameter before it's definitely assigned. Look at your code:

```
static void Fun(out int q, out int g)  
{  
    q = q + 1;  
    g = g + 1;  
}
```

In each case, the right hand side of the assignment expression uses an out parameter, and that out parameter hasn't been given a value yet. `out` parameters are initially not definitely assigned, and must be definitely assigned before the method returns (other than via an exception)

If the idea is to increment both parameters, you should use `ref` instead.

```
static void Fun(ref int q, ref int g)  
{  
    q = q + 1;  
    g = g + 1;  
}
```

Or more simply:

```
static void Fun(ref int q, ref int g)  
{  
    q++;
    g++;
}
```

You'll need to change the calling code to:

```
Fun(ref p, ref f);
```

Comment: That means I can't do it with out parameter?

Comment: @Maddy: Well you can't do anything that requires the value of the parameter before it's assigned within the method, no. Bear in mind that you could have written `int p, f; Fun(out p, out f);` - what would you have expected the values to be in that case?

Comment: The same Answer as I got from your method however i was trying to get it with the help op OUT parameter...

Comment: @Maddy: *Why*? You're trying to use `out` parameters for something that they're explicitly not designed for... they're called `out` because data comes *out* via them, rather than *in*.